Can't make Cloud Run service public
I have a Cloud Run service that is built from a docker container in Artifact Registry. This docker container runs a nextJS project, which should be accessible to the public.
The problem is, I keep getting a 403 Forbidden error. I have already set the ingress control to All.
I'm not sure how much I should anonymize, so I just replaced/censored everything that looked to be specific to the project.
Here's the service.yaml generated by running the command gcloud run services describe demo --format export > service.yaml:
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    run.googleapis.com/ingress: all
    run.googleapis.com/ingress-status: all
    run.googleapis.com/launch-stage: BETA
    run.googleapis.com/max-surge: '0'
    run.googleapis.com/minScale: '1'
  labels:
    cloud.googleapis.com/location: us-central1
  name: demo
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        autoscaling.knative.dev/maxScale: '100'
        run.googleapis.com/client-name: cloud-console
        run.googleapis.com/startup-cpu-boost: 'true'
    spec:
      containerConcurrency: 80
      containers:
      - image: us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/<img>
        name: demo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: http1
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1000m
            memory: 512Mi
        startupProbe:
          failureThreshold: 1
          periodSeconds: 240
          tcpSocket:
            port: 8080
          timeoutSeconds: 240
      serviceAccountName: <service acc>@developer.gserviceaccount.com
      timeoutSeconds: 300
  traffic:
  - latestRevision: true

If I understand it correctly, the annotations section is indicating that all requests should be allowed
Here's the Dockerfile I'm sending to the Artifact Registry. This docker image runs locally with no problems on port 8080, via the command docker run --publish 8080:8080 -it demo:$(TAG). I have tried to add publish and 8080:8080 to the service as container command and container arguments.:
# Use the official Node.js 18 image as base
# Build stage
FROM node:18-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /app/
COPY ./nextjs/package.json ./nextjs/package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./nextjs .
RUN npm run build

# Run stage
FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /app/
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1
ENV NODE_ENV production

# Copy only the built app from build image
COPY --from=build /app/public ./public
COPY --from=build /app/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=build /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=build /app/node_modules ./node_modules

EXPOSE 8080
ENV PORT 8080
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]

Here are the scripts in package.json:
"scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev -p 8080",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start -p 8080",
        "lint": "next lint",
        "artifactregistry-login": "npx google-artifactregistry-auth"
    },

And finally, some of the information I see in the logs:

This matches what I see when I run the nextJS project locally.
Here's the log of the request that resulted in a 403:
{
  httpRequest: {9}
  insertId: "66350577000c6befb6ec089b"
  logName: "projects/<project id>/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Frequests"
  receiveTimestamp: "2024-05-03T15:40:39.817385240Z"
  resource: {2}
  severity: "WARNING"
  spanId: "7903654621911405229"
  textPayload: "The request was not authenticated. Either allow unauthenticated invocations or set the proper Authorization header. Read more at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/authenticating Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#unauthorized-client"
  timestamp: "2024-05-03T15:40:39.773765Z"
  trace: "projects/<project id>/traces/4969ee0ddfdd2dc827013033afab8902"
  traceSampled: true
  }

There is a mention of "proper authorization headers". Are they still necessary if ingress control is set to All? Is this a problem with the service's configuration? Or something else entirely?

By default, the cloud run service are deployed in "secured" mode. It means you must include an authorization header to be authorized to access the Cloud Run service. Here you aren't, you got a 403.
If you want to validate this, you can try this command
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" <your URL>


To solve the issue, you can make your service public. The equivalent of this sentence is to authorize allUsers to access the service, with the role run.invoker
Therefore, you can run this command
gcloud run services add-iam-policy-binding SERVICE_NAME \
--member=allUsers \
--role=roles/run.invoker

You can also to the same thing with the console.

You can notice that the gcloud run deploy command has a parameter named --allow-unauthenticated to do the same thing. But it's only a convenient parameter.
I mean, the gcloud CLI will perform 2 actions:

first deploy the service
then grant allUsers on the service

With your YAML you only deploy the service, then you have to grant allUsers on it.
Note: you have to do it only once, not after each deployment
